# Php error sum (exponential)

Tags: php

I have an array of values, e.g.

```
+10.00
-5.00
+0.75
-5.75
```

Their sum must be zero, instead I read an  `-3,5527136788005E-15` at screen.

This is my code:

```
$currSum = 0;


foreach ($transactions as $key=>$value)
{
    $currSum += (float)$value['amountFinal'];
    echo '<p>sum is: '.$currSum.'</p>';
}
```

I did try with and without the `(float)` cast.

Data being from MySQL.

This is the `$transactions` array (example)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idTransactions] => 42809
            [amountFinal] => 1.95
            [idAccount] => 143
            [dateTransaction] => 2014-04-11 16:29:37

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [idTransactions] => 43455
            [amountFinal] => 1.50
            [idAccount] => 143
            [dateTransaction] => 2014-04-17 16:06:53

        )
)
```

Edit: I need to calculate sum step by step because, if sum is zero, I need to:

1 - store [idTransactions] in another array
2 - delete idTranscation from MySQL.

(no problem for 1 and 2, but if $curSum != 0 I cannot achieve my goal)

Comment: What is in $value['amountFinal']? Can you post  it please?

Comment: can you please `print_r($transactions)`? perhaps you're not really aware of what that index is.

Comment: @briosheje or just `var_dump($value['amountFinal']);`

Comment: @Loko: yes, but the problem may also be that $transactions might not be an associative array at all, who knows! :P

Comment: @briosheje edited as requested. Thank you

Comment: @Loko edited as requested. Thank you

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/floating-point/info .

Comment: Looks fine **[here](http://ideone.com/B4D7iG)**.

Comment: @sineverba why you want to do it with php? Why not doing it with MySQL directly? With a function and/or cascade delete? Or using mysql transactions. Check this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html and this http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with some weird rounding error in PHP or mysql or between them, I'm guessing. If you are fairly certain that n digits of precision will be enough then you can simply do something like this (using n=5):

```
$currSum += round($value['amountFinal'], 5);
```

Or, better yet (for performance as well as being sure that it is the *result* that is being rounded) just check at the final display/comparison point:

```
foreach ($transactions as $key=>$value)
{
    $currSum += (float)$value['amountFinal'];
    echo '<p>sum is: '.round($currSum, 5).'</p>';
}
if (round($currSum, 5) == 0) {
    # do whatever processing you wanted to do...
}
```

Comment: How about rounding your final result as you display/compare it?

Comment: I found another way: $amount = number_format($value['amountFinal'], 2, '.', '');
   $currSum = number_format($currSum+$amount, 2, '.', '');

Comment: Saving as a string prevents any kind of rounding errors, it's true, but it sure is going to slow things down, I would think...